# Можно ли отправлять данные вида Json в ms sql

Tags: java, sql, api

Задача: создаю api, связывающее программное обеспечение, которое сохраняет сообщения из разных мессенджеров и мою базу данных.

Вопрос: можно ли отправлять в базу ms sql данные вида Json.

Что есть: использую Spring-boot, преобразовываю поступающие данные Json в обычные типы String. А дальше отправляю в базу данных ms sql.

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы я мог отправлять данные вида Json сразу в базу данных?

Comment: в последних версиях ms sql есть поддержка JSON столбцов, а если нет, дак пишите в обычные текстовые, при чем тут `int` не понятно.

Comment: Да, по поводу int ошибка(поправил). Хорошо, спасибо. Можете сделать ваш комментарий ответом, отмечу его правильным. Если ещё покажете как именно отправлять, то буду благодарен. Если есть информация с какой версии есть поддержка Json, то тоже отлично будет.

Comment: пока вы не собираетесь работать непосредственно с JSON контентом на стороне СУБД, то есть делать из него выборки, то вам его наличие/отсутствие должно быть безразлично. а в чем ваше преобразование то заключается, что хотите от него избавится (я с java/spring) не знаком, вы лучше приведите пример, того, как вы данные получаете, и как отправляете в базу. Потому что суть вопроса, честно сказать пока что не понятна

Comment: Данные я принимаю с помощью Spring-boot, где преобразовываю все пришедшие данные Json в обычные переменные и затем загружаю в базу данных с помощью команды save. Дела обстоят так: я реализую api для связывания сторонней программы(которая отправляет данные) и своей базы данных(которая принимает эти данные).